# In node* newNode=new node() , whose address is exactly getting returned by new here?

Tags: memory-management, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation, new-operator, memory-address

```
node* newNode=new node();
```

Here node is a typical linked list node class and newNode is the pointer used to dynamically create a new node containing `int data` and `node* next` attributes. Please tell exactly which address gets returned by the `new` keyword and getting stored in the `newNode` here?

For instance in `int* p = arr[n];` , the address of `arr` or `arr[0]` is stored specifically.

Answer (score 0):

There is lot of behind the scenes are happening when you are specifying `new` keyword. The context of "which address gets returned by the new keyword" is not the primary thing to focus, rather you need to know how a program (more specifically a process) deals with memory via Operating System.

### what is process?

a process is more than a program code, which sometimes referred as text section; it also includes current activity as represented by the value of `program counter` and contents of the processor's registers.

a process generally includes:

1. the process stack, which contains temporary data such as function parameters, return addresses and local variables.
2. the data section, which contains global variables.
3. a process also include a heap area (which is important for your question), which is memory that is dynamically allocated during process runtime.

[image: memory management by a process]

### How memory allocated dynamically?

The new operator creates the object using that memory, and then returns a pointer containing the address of the memory that has been allocated.

```
  new int; // dynamically allocate an integer.
```

Most often, we’ll assign the return value to our own pointer variable so we can access the allocated memory later.

```
 int *ptr{ new int };
```

We can then perform indirection through the pointer to access the memory:

```
  *ptr = 7;
```

Also some points to mention:

1. when you are requesting some memory by `new` keyword, the Operating System first search for free memory needed to fulfill your requirement from `heap` area (as mentioned above), if OS finds the memory, it is allocated to your variable/s.
2. when you are done with your process, the process itself return the memory back to the OS, so that it can be used by another program's process.

REFERENCE: OPERATING SYSTEM CONCEPTS BY SILBERSCHATZ, GALVIN AND GAGNE.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a detailed answer but I am trying here to understand that if the node class has two attributes, one being an int and the other a node pointer than how will a single memory address be allocated to them in the heap and returned? I mean the node in the heap should logically occupy space equal to that of one int and one node pointer right?

Comment: the answer is `yes`; when you are creating a variable it doesn't matter the variable is complex type (generally is a combination of two/more types) or simple (single variable), the OS will always check the certain amount is free or not for allocating your request, if it so, it will assigned corresponding to your request.

the behaviour will always be same.